# Can't get custom cell in CollectionView to work properly

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I created a custom cell for my `CollectionView`, however, I got problems with displaying the cell as I want.
This is the code for the custom cell:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CardCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupCell()
        setupViewsInCell()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupCell()
        setupViewsInCell()
    }

    var postTitle: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "POST TITLE"
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        label.textColor = UIColor.appColors.mainBlack
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return label
    }()

    //postImage need to be the image the user uploaded.
    var postImage: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "placeholder-image"))
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        image.clipsToBounds = true
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return image
    }()

    var likeImage: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "like"))
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        image.clipsToBounds = true
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return image
    }()

    var numberOfLikes: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "20"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 8)
        label.textColor = UIColor.appColors.mainBlack
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return label
    }()

    var dislikeImage: UIImageView = {
        let image = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "dislike"))
        image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        image.clipsToBounds = true
        image.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return image
    }()

    var numberOfDislikes: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "34"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 8)
        label.textColor = UIColor.appColors.mainBlack
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return label
    }()

    func setupCell(){
        backgroundColor = UIColor.appColors.mainWhite
        layer.cornerRadius = 10
        clipsToBounds = true
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.25).cgColor
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        layer.shadowOpacity = 1
        layer.shadowRadius = 2
        layer.masksToBounds = false
    }

    func setupViewsInCell(){

        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [likeImage, numberOfLikes, dislikeImage, numberOfDislikes])
        stackView.axis = .horizontal
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.addSubview(postTitle)
        self.addSubview(postImage)
        self.addSubview(stackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            postTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 0),
            postTitle.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 8),
            postImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: postTitle.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            postImage.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor),
            postImage.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.rightAnchor),
            postImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 30),
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: postImage.bottomAnchor, constant: 50),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leftAnchor, constant: 8),
            stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.frame.width / 2),
        ])
    }
}
```

The few problems I have, and couldn't find solution for are this:

1. The title isn't even showing, I tried to change the constant few times, but still nothing.
2. constraits problem, I set the stackView topAnchor to the postImage bottomAnchor, but it still won't work.
   This is a screenshot from the simulator.
3. as you can see in the screenshot below, the collection view is off to the side for some reason. I'm guessing it is a collectionView problem and not a cell problem, but I couldn't find a solution for this neither.

[image]

Comment: It would be super helpful if you were able to break down each problem into separate issues. There's a good bit of code in your snipped and there could be any number of reasons why your labels are not showing up. I would recommend you strip out all the suspect code and add it back in line-by-line as you understand what it is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Change this constant to negative `postImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: postTitle.bottomAnchor, constant: 10)`, when you use `bottomAnchor` or `rightAnchor` the constant need to be negative. If you want to understand more, see [Bottom and Right constraints of view are negative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42995934/bottom-and-right-constraints-of-view-are-negative)
2. The same problem with the constraint constant `stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: postImage.bottomAnchor, constant: 50)`, try to change to -50
3. If you want to create Collection View with dynamic cell height, you need to calculate the cell size. You can do this by creating your custom view layout, see
   https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest
   this is a good tutorial to create a custom `UICollectionViewLayout`,
   or you can calculate the cell size inside the method  `func
   collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout
   collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt
   indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize` using the `systemLayoutSizeFitting`, if all constraints are set right, this method will return the size of the cell, but you need to remember that this function will be called every
   time a cell appears, a solution to this is save the height and check
   if a content was already used to calculate the height of a cell. If
   you need to change the height of the cell in another time, you need
   to update the saved value as well or delete it to calculate the size
   again.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 50)
        let dummyCell = Cell(frame: frame)
        let targetSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 1000)
        let dummyData = data[indexPath.row]
        dummyCell.data = dummyData
        dummyCell.layoutIfNeeded()
        let height = max(MINIMUM_CELL_SIZE, 
         dummyCell.systemLayoutSizeFitting(targetSize).height)
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: height)
    }
```